# What was the best late Nova rocket design among the request for proposals NASA received?

Tags: mars, apollo-program, rocket-equation

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_%28rocket%29) the *late* Nova rocket was a "larger version" of the Saturn 5, meant to send manned missions to Mars. Some requests for proposals were obtained, but the whole project was sadly scrapped once it became apparent NASA would not receive a decent budget any longer once Apollo was cancelled.

Question: What was the best design among the received proposals? By best here it is meant what NASA regarded as the best at the time. Were they even properly evaluated by NASA before the project was scrapped? If not, then the answer is simply they were not evaluated. Perhaps they have been evaluated later just for academic interest?

Comment: Define "best" to avoid getting closed as opinion-based

Comment: Implied as best according to NASA's own criteria, but I've now edited it to be more explicit.

Comment: It is possible the evaluation of the designs never got to a stage where one version was chosen as superior.

Comment: I believe that would make the answer to the question simply that they were not evaluated.